# Remote Debugging live server with asp.net Visual Studtio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging, remote-server, static-ip-address

I am remote debugging asp.net application with visual studio 2008

the server i m debugging is a dedicated server with some static ip like 123.456.7.8
with iis 6.0

i have a user account to remote desktop connection with some username like
**abc** and pass as **abc**

i have created a user account on my local machine with the same username and password.

this i have done to make remote debugging connection using **windows authentication**

when starting the remote debugger on remote machine it says:

```
Msvsmon started a new server named 'user@xy1245'. Waiting for new connections.]
```

where **xy1245** is the pc name it comes with username as follows : user\xy1245

to connect to this machine i have tried the following steps:

In vs 2008, Debug -> Attach to process :

Transport: Default.

Qualifier: user@xy1245

i have also tried user@123.456.7.8 , 123.456.7.8\user@xy1245

but says does not exists or firewall blocking

but when i try the same with remote no authentication (**native code only**) .

Msvsmon started a new server named 'xy1245:4015'. Waiting for new connections.]

then in local vs 2008, i say 123.456.7.8:4015, it connects perfectly.

Is there any step i m missing, or anything i am doing wrong??